# Valgrind - callgrind Profiler : How to know which function is taking more time

Tags: c++, valgrind, callgrind

I am trying to profile for certain executable using valgrind - callgrind tool.
I have created annotated output using `callgrind_annotate --auto=yes`.
The created output tells me about the Ir count , which as per my understanding is the number of times that particular instruction was called, but I want to know which section of the code is taking maximum time in execution.

How can I know about it ?

In my application I want to find the the portion which is taking more time ... there may be cases certain function is called more number of time than other .. but the function which is called less number of time is taking more time than the other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use valgrind to know time(in seconds) spent in each function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663614/use-valgrind-to-know-timein-seconds-spent-in-each-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the UI [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html). It makes much easier to understand your application flow and to detect possible bottlenecks.

Comment: I have not yet installed the KCachegrind ... but wont its output will be again on basis of event count.

Comment: `kcachegrind` can show the time-usage of function calls?

Comment: Where is it / how can I show it?

Comment: It's been a while I have not used KCachegrind. It used to be included on valgrind. Their github repo is active though https://github.com/KDE/kcachegrind